# Evaluating a summation while suppressing zero raised to a negative power

Tags: summation

I want to compute the following multiple summation.

```
m=1;
n=1;

output = 
  Sum[
    Sum[
      Sum[
        Sum[
          Sum[
            (m-l)!/(k-l+l1)! c^(k+l1-l) a^(m-k-l1) b^l1 (l)!/(l-k+x1)! f^(l-k+x1) d^(k-x1) 1/(i-x1)! g^(i-x1) e^x1,
            {i,0,n-l}],
          {x1,0,k}],
        {l1,0,m-k}],
      {l,0,m}],
    {k,0,m}]

(*a + b c + d + c e + b f + a g + b c g *)
```

Now declaring the value of $b,c,e,f,g$,

```
b=0;
c=0;
e=0;
f=0;
g=0;
```

the output becomes $a+d$. However, I want to evaluate the summation after declaring the value of $b,c,e,f,g$ which results in showing error due to quantities like $0^{-1}$ appear in the summand.

I want to see if mathematica can simplify the summation in form of known special function under the condition $b=c=e=f=g=0$ for general $m, n$.

Comment: You can just use one `Sum` and then include all iteration variable definitions in a series making this better to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Block`. Like so:

```
m = 1;
n = 1;

b = 0;
c = 0;
e = 0;
f = 0;
g = 0;

output =
  Block[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g},
    Sum[
      Sum[
        Sum[
          Sum[
            Sum[
              (m - l)!/(k - l + l1)! c^(k + l1 - l) a^(m - k - l1) b^l1 (l)!/(l - k + x1)! f^(l - k + x1) d^(k - x1) 1/(i - x1)! g^(i - x1) e^x1, 
              {i, 0, n - l}],
            {x1, 0, k}],
          {l1, 0, m - k}],
        {l, 0, m}],
      {k, 0, m}]]
```

> `a + d`

Answer (score 2):

The natural way to work with formulas (*symbolic*) and values (*numeric*) is to use *rules*:

```
m = 1;
n = 1;
parameters = {b, c, e, f, g};
parameterValues = Thread[ parameters -> ConstantArray[0, Length @ parameters] ];

term = Sum[
    (m - l)!/(k - l + l1)! c^(k + l1 - l) a^(m - k - l1) b^l1 (l)!/(l - k + x1)! 
     f^(l - k + x1) d^(k - x1) 1/(i - x1)! g^(i - x1) e^x1,
    (* sequence of summation: i - x1 - l1 - l - k *)
    {k, 0, m},
    {l, 0, m},
    {l1, 0, m - k},
    {x1, 0, k},
    {i, 0, n - l}
];

term /. parameterValues
```

> a + d